# Git merge feature branches on deploy with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano, branching-and-merging

I am looking for a simple way to merge feature branches into my development branch on deployment, while still keeping them separate in my repository.

I am deploying my develop branch to my staging server, but want to prevent issues from multiple developers pushing many feature branches in the development branch which would make it difficult to create releases with certain features.

Ideally, I have the following branches:

develop
feature1
feature2

On deployment, the following is done:

Merge: develop + feature1 + feature2 (though keep these branches separate identities in the repository)
 and then deploy to the staging server

I am using Capistrano, and figured I may be able to maintain a separate staging branch, and dynamically merge and push these branches based on a file that holds the feature branch names, but I am not sure of an elegant way to accomplish this with Capistrano.

Comment: before deploying development branch, you can merge feature branches into development branch, do not delete feature branches. And if any conflict is there you can easily resolve that before deployment. Do not merge feature branches into development branch while deploying it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not want to merge the feature branches into the develop branch. I want to keep them out of the repository until the features have been approved on staging. With several developers working on different features, it's hard to approve features and create a release without cherry-picking. The idea is to keep all unapproved features out of develop until tested, yet still have them all available for testing on the staging server. I am looking for an automated method to merge these branches at deployment based on a list of feature branches, keeping develop untouched.